# Windows 10 UWP Javascript App Download Permissions

Tags: javascript, uwp

I have created a UWP app written in HTML, CSS and Javascript by installing Visual Studio 17 and selecting Javascript - Blank App as a new project, adding the HTML, CSS and Javascript files along with a few images into the project directory, accepting the default Internet (Client) permission and running the package.

Nearly everything works as I expected however one issue that has caused me some grief concerns the ability to create and write a text file to a user selected folder on the C:\ drive. In fact I cannot even create a text file in the users Downloads directory.

I have found the following information on the Microsoft Developer site

"By default, your app can only access files and folders in the user's Downloads folder that your app created. However, you can gain access to files and folders in the user's Downloads folder by calling a file picker (FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker) so that users can navigate and pick files or folders for your app to access".

Can I invoke a file picker from inside javascript and would I need to add more permissions, or do I need to transition to a WebView2 based app and do this in C#?

Also where exactly is the "user's Downloads folder that your app created"? Is this a sub-folder under "Downloads"? Does it need to be created? If so, can it be created from javascript?

Or am I simply missing some permission in the manifest? If so which?

All help on this matter would be very gratefully received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I invoke a file picker from inside javascript and would I need to add more permissions, or do I need to transition to a WebView2 based app and do this in C#?

Yes, you could call a FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker from javascript. You could check this sample: [FilePicker](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/archived/FilePicker). This is an archived official JS sample about file pickers but it still works for JS.

> Also where exactly is the "user's Downloads folder that your app created"? Is this a sub-folder under "Downloads"? Does it need to be created? If so, can it be created from javascript?

The system will automatically create a folder named by your app's name in the Downloads library first when you create files in the Downloads library. It's a sub-folder of the Downloads library. Let's say it's called `MyApp` folder. All the folders and files your app created are listed in your app's sub-folder.

For example, you called `DownloadsFolder.CreateFolderAsync("New Folder")` method to create a folder. When the code is executed, a folder named `New Folder` will be created under the `MyApp` folder.

This behavior is very easy to test. You could make a try and it will helps you to understand.

Your app could access the `MyApp` folder directly by default. But not other files or folders under the Downloads library. If you want to access other files or folders, then you have to use FilePickers to get the files as I mentioned above.